# Can't locate resource file in JAR

Tags: java, jar, meta-inf

I have a class in my Java application, which reads a resource folder which is located in **src/main/resources**. So, in that class, I am specifying the resource folder as:

```
public static final String RES_LOCATION = "./src/main/resources";
```

The program runs fine. But when I make a jar and use that as a dependency in another project, that above class fails as it cannot find the resource folder.

Any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read particular file from that directory as a classpath resource instead of `java.io.File`

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("relative/class/path/to/resource");
```

Comment: If I want to load files with particular extensions, what do you suggest?

Comment: use the same technique but put the full file path in classpath and related to the cp. so replace `resource` in this example with `1.txt` for example

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the wrong resource path, you need to load the resource like resources 
'public static final String RES_LOCATION = "resources"' as src/main will not be present.

Comment: Problem is, I was getting the name of the resource folder (src/main/resource) and listing all the files in that folder based on a particular extension. How can I achieve that in the jar?

Answer (score 0):

`./src/main/resources` is related to the structure of your project and is not the same when you package your code to `.jar` file. Both structures are very different and it can affect the way you access your file.

The best practice to access a file in a resource can be found on this page : https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/